# Prove that $p^2 | (p!+p)$ for any prime $p.$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that $p^2 | (p!+p)$ for any prime $p.$

So far I have: If $p$ is prime, then $p$ divides $[(p-1)!+1].$ Therefore 
$(p-1)!+1\equiv 0 \operatorname{mod}p.$ Where do I go from there?

Comment: If $a\mid b$ then $ac\mid bc$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(p-1)!=px-1$ where $x\in \Bbb Z.$ Therefore $p!+p=p\cdot (p-1)!+p=p(px-1)+p=p^2x.$

Comment: An easy proof of Wilson's Theorem: Let $G$ be a finite commutative group. Let $P$ be the product of all the members of $G$. Members of $G$ that are not their own inverses come in pairs ($x$ & $x^{-1}$) that cancel each other in $P$. So $P$ is the product of those $x\in G$ that are their own inverses. If  $p$ is prime and $G=\{1,...,p-1\}$ with multiplication mod $p$, then the only members of $G$ that are their own inverses are $1$ and $p-1.$

Answer (score 3):

$(p-1)!+1=0 \pmod p$ is Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

multiplying both sides by $ p $

to get

$$ p(p-1)! + p = p( p n) $$

where  $n$ is natural number

hence

$$ p! + p = p^2 n $$